# Canyon Lux CF 6 - DT Swiss X 1900 - Tubeless

Tags: rims, tubeless

Since it will be my first conversion to tubeless can anyone advise me on what I need to buy?

And can I do it on my own? Is it possible to ruin the rim?

Comment: That wheel set may have come pre-taped for tubeless and also with valves. Is the rim tape an adhesive kind with the dt logo on it?

Comment: DT Swiss certainly says they are tubeless ready. My DT Swiss PR 1400 DICUT came with tubeless tape installed and tubeless valves in the package. So you just need tyres, sealant and an air compressor.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need tubeless valves, some sort of sealant, and some means to get the tire beads seated.

The stock tires listed with that [Canyon model](https://www.canyon.com/en-us/mountain-bikes/cross-country-bikes/lux/lux-trail/lux-trail-cf-6/3227.html#all-components-section-tab) are the Schwalbe Racing Ralph SR TLE EVO 2.35", and TLE is a synonym for tubeless compatibility. I would guess that decent performance MTBs almost universally ship with tubeless compatible tires these days in any case, even if they are not set up tubeless from the factory.

You should verify that the stock rim tape on your wheel is tubeless compatible. You could contact Canyon. DT Swiss’s [product page](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/wheels/wheels-mtb/cross-country/x-1900-spline) for the wheel set doesn’t seem to clearly state this. I think the tape is likely tubeless compatible, but I can’t be certain. I know that the rim strip my last set of *road* rims came with was *not* tubeless compatible by itself, but that’s a different discipline and those were bought in 2018. If you need new tape, get something just a bit wider than the internal width of your rims (which is not clear, because DT Swiss’ page says 22.5mm, 25mm). You will need to punch a hole in the tape for the valve, and I believe just scissors are enough if there isn’t a premade hole.

To get the beads seated, you could just use a couple of CO2 cartridges. You likely need some sort of blast of air. some floor pumps come with compressed air chambers to enable tubeless inflation. Some tubeless tires may seat themselves with just a floor pump. You could also get a Presta inflator and go to a gas station. You could ask a bike store to blast some air in. You could go and buy an air compressor if you plan on changing a lot of tires. There are numerous options.

For valve stems, I have typically recommended brass ones rather than aluminum ones. The latter are definitely available in bright anodized colors and they are slightly lighter. They may be more prone to snapping than brass.

I believe that is the absolute minimum you need for a tubeless conversion from your current setup.